# как запустить любое приложение из своего в android?

Tags: android, app

я знаю, что можно запускать различные приложения в android через intent, но так можно запустить приложение для конкретной задачи, можно ли из моего приложения запустить любое выбранное пользователем приложение и как, если можно?

Comment: я только нашёл это, но возможно вот решение: https://android-tools.ru/coding/poluchenie-spiska-prilozhenij-v-android/

Answer (score 0):

вообщем я нашёл решение, может кому пригодится:

```
val list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER), 0)//информация о приложениях
for (u in list){
   packageManager.getApplicationLabel(list[u].activityInfo.applicationInfo) //название приложения
   list[u].loadIcon(pack)//иконка приложения
}
```

запустить приложение можно так:

```
val LaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(list[u].activityInfo.packageName) // в скобках название пакета
startActivity(LaunchIntent)
```